# Multiseat on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

How to make 2 or more users to use the same Mac OS at the same time? As I know for windows there is Aster, for linux there is Xorg.
I researched this topic for quite some time and cannot find a satisfactory solution for mac. The only thing I could find is connecting through remote desktop to the computer in a special way. But there are a lot of problems with it:

1. You still have to use a spare PC to connect to the mac
2. Remote desktops are very slow and buggy, even video encoded like Nomachine is not suitable for gaming at all
3. It takes some time to connect to the remote desktop each time. Especially because of the special way you need to connect

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about the intended use here? You mention gaming in the question, development in the comments beneath an answer. The hardware/performance requirements for these two uses are quite different, so being specific might help to find solutions.

Comment: Rather than writing "As I know for windows there is Aster", which is meaningless for many users who might otherwise help you, please describe what is "your" need.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the use, I was convinced that the only viable solution is multiseat setup so I did not consider other options. So, mostly I would like to use my computer as a two seats xcode programming station. Gaming is not that important, so we can forget about it. As I already said VMs did not work for me quite well, and all resourses I could find said that a Mac VM does not support GPU forwarding which I believe causes those performance issues. If I am wrong please provide an example of VM setup which would had "5% performance loss at max".

Comment: You’re wrong on multiple layers actually :-) GPU forwarding is supported. However it is not what is the cause of performance issues - you can easily have great performance without it. GPU forwarding has its own set of disadvantages that you probably won’t like in your setup. Try VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop for a fast setup!

Comment: What about this? https://www.quora.com/Will-VMware-Fusion-ever-support-accelerated-graphics-for-an-OS-X-guest

Answer (score 1):

There are no native multi-seat solutions for current macOS that allows multiple, simultaneous users on the same Mac each with their own screen, keyboard and mouse.

You can create a multi-seat solution by running Windows or Linux on the Mac instead of macOS.

In theory you could also run for example a native Linux and virtualise several macOS instances to provide multi-seat usage of macOS on the Mac. In practice, you'll have licensing worries amongst other things.

Comment: I want to use such an environment to use xcode. Windows and linux do not support it, and virtualizing mac os seems to be a very slow solution in terms of performance.

Comment: Well, virtualization is your only choice in this case. The performance penalty of virtualization on modern hardware is not very large when you want to run an application such as Xcode.

Comment: I tried vmware with vmware tools, and it is still pretty slow. One of the reasons I suspect is video card is not forwarded to a vm as I know.

Comment: @SimonMoshenko I think your best bet will be to purchase a set of last-gen Mac Minis.

Comment: You can definitely forward a video card to the VM if you want. However it sounds a bit odd that you find it so slow - have you tried only on old hardware? Modern hardware runs VMs with very little performance loss - for development I would say something like a 5% loss at max.

Comment: answered in the question's section